# How to strip a NiFi flow file contents from a flow file?

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm using a ReplaceText processor and "replacing" all matching characters with nothing. This effectively removes the flow file contents, but it seems inefficient.

I'm done processing with the flow file contents and will just be writing metrics from the attributes that are remaining.

Is there a better way to get rid of the flow file contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do a Literal Replace with an Evaluation Mode of `Entire Text` it should be very fast as there is no regex matching or overwriting or anything else, just writing nothing to the outgoing Flow File.